# Please solve the problem given in the image.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Problem** Find the value of $$\frac{1}{\sqrt 1 + \sqrt 3} + \frac 1 {\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5} + \dots + \frac 1 {\sqrt {1087} + \sqrt{1089}}$$

I cant figure out how to solve this problem. I cant use summation.

Comment: Brilliant.org is a nice site, but you should try to solve the exercises yourself! :-) The hints given below are surely enough for you to connect the dots and solve the problem :) (I don't want to appear as a moralist, though, so I'll say that the answer is $16$ (unless I'm mistaken ) :-) )

Comment: I have been trying to solve it for 3 hours

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is too specific to be of any future value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complement the other answer:

**Hint:**

$$\frac12(\sqrt{n+4} - \sqrt{n+2}) + \frac12(\sqrt{n+2} - \sqrt{n}) = \frac12(\sqrt{n+4} - \sqrt{n}) + \frac12(\sqrt{n+2} - \sqrt{n+2})$$
$$ = \frac12(\sqrt{n+4} - \sqrt{n})$$

A rearrangement of terms shows that they collapse

EDIT:
Let $a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}}$ where $n\in\{1,2,3,...,544\}$
(notice $n = 544 \implies2n+1 = 1089$)

$$a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}}\frac{\sqrt{2n-1}-\sqrt{2n+1}}{\sqrt{2n-1}-\sqrt{2n+1}}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{2n-1}-\sqrt{2n+1}}{(2n-1) - (2n + 1)} = \frac12(\sqrt{2n+1} - \sqrt{2n-1})$$

And we try to evaluate
$$\sum_{n=1}^{544} a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{544}\frac12(\sqrt{2n+1} - \sqrt{2n-1})$$
writing out a few terms we see:
$$2\sum_{n=1}^{544} a_n = (\sqrt3 - \sqrt1) + (\sqrt{5} - \sqrt3) + ... +(\sqrt{1087} - \sqrt{1085})+(\sqrt{1089} - \sqrt{1087})$$
$$=\sqrt{1089} + (\sqrt{1087} - \sqrt{1087}) + (\sqrt{1085} - \sqrt{1085}) +...+(\sqrt3 -\sqrt3) - \sqrt1 $$

So $$\sum_{n=1}^{544} a_n = \frac12(\sqrt{2(544) + 1} - 1) = \frac12(\sqrt{1089} - 1) = 16$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $$\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+2}}{(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+2})(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+2})}=\dfrac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+2}}{n-n-2}=\ldots$$